# Find a data in richtextBox, I have used the Rich Text format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am try find a data in **richTextBox** . I can try with the option of richTextBox1.Find("textBox1.text").I am new in programming . when the run this code one time find the data and can't a select whole page. I have try again and again but can't do this. 
Once again i am  telling what is my problem, my problem is find a data  in the whole page. but find a once time data and stop. My coding part is below...plz help me...
thanks in advance..

```
 private void gOToToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  if (richTextBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            FindMyText("joginder", 0, richTextBox1.Text.Length);

        }
    }
    public int FindMyText(string searchText, int searchStart, int searchEnd)
    {         
        int returnValue = -1;            
        if (searchText.Length > 0 && searchStart >= 0)
        {               
            if (searchEnd > searchStart || searchEnd == -1)
            {                   
                int indexToText = richTextBox1.Find(searchText, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);                    
                if (indexToText >= 0)
                {                        
                    returnValue = indexToText;
                } }
        }

        return returnValue;
   }  }
```

Comment: hi can any one help me

Comment: Is it that your code is finding ONE match, and you are wanting to find ALL matches?

Comment: yes sir g, i have find all data

Comment: Another thing to note: are you doing this in ASP.Net or in Windows Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat your search through the text, advancing the start position.

Update your code as follows:

```
public void FindAllMatches(string searchText)
{
    int start = 0;
    int increment = searchText.Length;
    bool complete = false;
    while (!complete)
    {
        start = richTextBox1.Find(searchText, start, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
        if (start >= 0) start += increment;
        else complete = true;
    }
}
```